Can open sets in $ℝ^n$ be finitely triangulated?
I'm reading Topological Manifolds by Lee and I just want to check whether I have misunderstood something about triangulations. The book describes how simplices $\left|σ\right|$ are closed in the geometric realization of their simplical complex $\left|k\right|$ and a triangulation homeomorphism , in a sense, maps these closed faces to the 'faces' of the space being triangulated. It also states that all $1$,$2$ and $3$ manifolds can be triangulated including manifolds without boundary homeomorphic to open sets in $R^n$.
Does this mean that for spaces homeomorphic to topologically open sets of $R^n$ , a triangulation will always require an infinite number of simplices (to create these open 'faces' from closed sets)? If this is the case, then i assume that the images online showing finite triangulations of shapes (assumedly in $R^n$) are all using closed sets?
(I may have misunderstood something in the area of thinking of this space as an embedding rather than by itself but I am unsure.)
Any response to help me understand this more clearly would be appreciated.

By the way, I notice that you have several answered questions but you have not accepted any answers. Here's something to keep in mind, excerpted from the tour: The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.

I apologize. I didn't know that the person asking the question was able to give that out!

No, this is not possible (addressing your title question); indeed, every triangulation of a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is a infinite triangulation.
For the proof, every space which has a finite triangulation is compact, because it is a union of finitely many compact sets. So if it is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ then it is closed. But because $\mathbb R^n$ is connected, its only subsets that are both open and closed are $\mathbb R^n$ itself and $\emptyset$.
